# How to send video via MMS? Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sms, mms

I'm currently writing a program where I want to send a 1MB video (.avi) via SMS from a VB.net application. I've seen a lot of SMS code where it is using a SMTP server (such as smtp.gmail.com) and sending an email to (phonenumber)@mobile.att.com (or whatever carrier). This will be an MMS.

In those cases, usually the user is sent just text. What is the best way to send a video file to that phone number, possibly without knowing the carrier? What I have seen suggested is a third party application, but the majority of them use only text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: SMS as Short Message Service? The system that allows sending 160 characters for each message?

Comment: Sorry, I mean MMS. I'll edit to reflect that.